# How can I specialize a template member function for std::vector<T>

Tags: c++, templates

I need to define a get method in two different ways. One for simple types T. And once for std::vector.

```
template<typename T>
const T& Parameters::get(const std::string& key)
{
    Map::iterator i = params_.find(key);
    ...
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(boost::get<std::string>(i->second));
    ...
}
```

How can I specialize this method for std::vector. As there the code should look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
const T& Parameters::get(const std::string& key)
{
    Map::iterator i = params_.find(key);
    std::vector<std::string> temp = boost::get<std::vector<std::string> >(i->second)
    std::vector<T> ret(temp.size());
    for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++){
         ret[i]=boost::lexical_cast<T>(temp[i]);
    }
    return ret;    
}
```

But I do not know how to specialize the function for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318458/template-specialization-of-template-class

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Don't specialize function template.**

- [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)
- [Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)

**Instead, use overload.**

Write a function template `get_impl` to handle the general case, and *overload* (not *specialize*) this to handle the specific case, then call `get_impl` from `get` as:

```
template<typename T>
const T& Parameters::get(const std::string& key)
{
     //read the explanation at the bottom for the second argument!
     return get_impl(key, static_cast<T*>(0) );
}
```

And here goes the actual implementations.

```
//general case
template<typename T>
const T& Parameters::get_impl(const std::string& key, T*)
{
    Map::iterator i = params_.find(key);
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(boost::get<std::string>(i->second));
}

//this is overload - not specialization
template<typename T>
const std::vector<T>& Parameters::get_impl(const std::string& key, std::vector<T> *)
{
      //vector specific code
}
```

The `static_cast<T*>(0)` in `get` is just a tricky way to disambiguate the call. The type of `static_cast<T*>(0)` is `T*`, and passing it as second argument to `get_impl` will help compiler to choose the correct version of `get_impl`. If `T` is not `std::vector`, the first version will be chosen, otherwise the second version will be chosen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: static_cast<T*>(nullptr)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: This is not working for me on gcc9, it still picks the non-vector impl

Comment: Great answer ! One additional comment: an alternative to a dummy second parameter is to make the API return the result by reference, i.e. in a second parameter.

Comment: @AntonBelov: That might not be possible always. Also, if possible, that might not be optimum. In some cases, there is nothing to be returned (i.e return `void`) and all that is done is a computation (state change, IO or so).

Answer (score 3):

Erm. call it something else? e.g.

```
template<typename T>
const T& Parameters::getVector(const std::string& key)
{
  Map::iterator i = params_.find(key);
  std::vector<std::string> temp = boost::get<std::vector<std::string> >(i->second)
  // T is already a vector
  T ret; ret.reserve(temp.size());
  for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++){
     ret.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<typename T::value_type>(temp[i]));
  }
  return ret;  
}
```

You'll have to call this as:

```
foo.getVector<std::vector<int> > ("some_key");
```

Nothing in your question precludes this.

Now, if you really do need to use `get()`, then you have to rely on partially specializing a structure, as function partial specialization is not supported by the language.

This is a lot more complicated, for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct getter
{
  const T& operator()(std::string const& key)
  {
    // default operations
  }
};

// Should double check this syntax 
template <typename T>
struct getter<std::vector<T, std::allocator<T> > >
{
  typedef std::vector<T, std::allocator<T> > VecT;
  const VecT& operator()(std::string const& key)
  {
    // operations for vector
  }
};
```

Then in you method becomes:

```
template<typename T>
const T& Parameters::get(const std::string& key)
{
  return getter<T>()(key); // pass the structures getter needs?
}
```

Comment: Do you have to call it in another name? Wouldn't overloading just do the trick?

Comment: @the_drow You cannot overload based on return type.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Sure you can with some template magic. `template<typename T> T ft(); template<> int ft<int>() { return 1; } template<> float ft<float>() { return 0; } struct f { template<typename T> operator T() { return ft<T>(); } }; int main() { int il = f(); float fl = f(); cout << il, fl; }` litb wrote this btw.

Comment: @Nim: Instead of making `getter` a class template, you could make `operator()` a function template **and** instead of defining one `operator()`, define two `operator()`, one for each case (general as well as specific). That way you would *not* need to specialize `getter`. There is also one plus point (syntactically): you could call this as : `getter()(key)` instead of `getter<T>()(key)`.

Comment: .... But either way, it has a drawback : `getter` cannot access members of `Parameters` class. So I think, it is better to make the actual implementations member of the class (like I've done), rather than defining new struct.

Comment: @Nawaz, definitely need to pass any state to the `getter` so that it can return the values.

Comment: @Nim: That can be done. But it makes thing unnecessarily complicate, for example; if `getter` needs to access `private/protected` members, then you've to make `getter` friend of the class.