# templated method with std::vector overload not taking hold

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but referring to the answer to this question:
[How can I specialize a template member function for std::vector<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314827/how-can-i-specialize-a-template-member-function-for-stdvectort)

if I try a simple example of this using GCC9 it simply does not work, and I cant understand why not.  Am I missing something here?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> foo( const std::vector<T> & )
{
    printf( "vector!\n" );
    return std::vector<T>();
}

template<typename T>
T foo( const T & )
{
    printf( "non vector!\n" );
    return T();
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>( *( int * ) nullptr);
    foo<std::vector<int>>( *( std::vector<int> * ) nullptr);
}
```

Outputs:

```
non vector!
non vector!
```

Comment: Your template parameter `T` is the type of the vector's elements, and you're not passing a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. (Explicit instantiations can be surprising.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
foo<std::vector<int>>( *( std::vector<int> * ) nullptr);
```

to

```
foo<int>( *( std::vector<int> * ) nullptr);
```

Your top template expects a typename T and the method takes a vector of T.

Comment: Even better, let template parameters be deduced.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I'd love to see an example, as I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: Something like `std::vector<int> someVector; foo(someVector);` without explicitly specifying the template parameter at all. But that does require you to know a lot about how overload resolution interacts with templated functions to be confident that `foo(someVector)` will call the first function with `T = int` and not the second function with `T = std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed this since i was originally calling with <> ( without the T*  argument ) and then neglected to consider the call site when I changed this